# MySQL query to get a list of user from conversation list

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql table chat like

```
+---------+-----------+-------------+----------------+
| chat_id | sender_id | receiver_id | msg            |
+---------+-----------+-------------+----------------+
|       1 |      1002 |        1001 | test           |
|       2 |      1001 |        1002 | test           |
|       3 |      1002 |        1001 | test           |
|       5 |      1001 |        1002 | asdf           |
|       6 |      1003 |        1001 | tesdf          |
|       9 |      1001 |        1003 | tasdfa a fasd  |
|      10 |      1001 |        1004 | dsf asdf a     |
|      11 |      1005 |        1001 | dsf asdf asdf  |
+---------+-----------+-------------+----------------+
```

There is conversation of user 1001 among users 1002,1003,1004,1005

I need a list of users(1002,1003,1004,1005) whom with user 1001 did conversation.

What will be the mysql query? please help me.

Answer (score 5):

You can select all records which a specific user you want to search is in either a `sender` or `receiver`. After that test if the sender's id is equal to the userid you want to search and if it is equal return receiver's id otherwise return sender. The `DISTINCT` keyword is supplied to show only unique ID on the list of result.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        CASE WHEN sender_id = 1001 
            THEN receiver_id 
            ELSE sender_id 
        END userID
FROM    tableName
WHERE   1001 IN (sender_id, receiver_id)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/960b9/1)

since you want to concatenate the row [based on your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760033/mysql-query-to-get-a-list-of-user-from-conversation-list/18760072#comment27654765_18760332)

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
                    CASE WHEN sender_id = 1001 
                        THEN receiver_id 
                        ELSE sender_id 
                    END) userID
FROM    tableName
WHERE   1001 IN (sender_id, receiver_id)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/960b9/2)

Answer (score 3):

Just try this

```
select  DISTINCT if(receiver_id='1001',sender_id,receiver_id) AS id
from    YourTable
where   (sender_id = 1001 OR receiver_id = 1001)
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT (
if( receiver_id = '1001', sender_id, receiver_id ) )
) AS concat
FROM chat
WHERE (
sender_id =1001
OR receiver_id =1001
)
```

I think you are aware about GROUP_CONCAT size issues. You can refer this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: It is fine, if I use select DISTINCT to remove duplicate. But I want to use GROUP_CONCAT to get as 1002,1003,1004,1005. How posible...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `union` to combine two queries where sender or receiver is 1001:

```
select  distinct sender_id
from    YourTable
where   receiver_id = 1001
union
select  distinct receiver_id
from    YourTable
where   sender_id = 1001
```

Comment: this can still possible return duplicate if ID exists on both sender and receiver.

Comment: @Zeus: The `union` will filter those duplicates out.  (A union that keeps duplicates is a `union all`.)

Answer (score 0):

HI Please check following query

select distinct receiver_id from table where distinct sender_id = 1001

Answer (score 0):

```
(select distinct receiver_id from table where sender_id = 1001)
union distinct
(select distinct sender_id from table where receiver_id = 1001);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course this could have come earlier, unfortunately I too have been struggling with the same question for 9 months. I hope this will unblock the Suez.

```
SELECT *,
CASE
WHEN sender_id = 1001
THEN receiver_id
ELSE sender_id 
END as user_id
FROM chats
WHERE chat_id IN (SELECT MAX(chat_id) 
FROM chats WHERE receiver_id= 1001 
OR sender_id = 1001
GROUP BY IF (sender_id=1001, receiver_id,sender_id) )
ORDER BY chat_id DESC
```